# iOS 10 Background connection for closed networks

Tags: ios, iphone, voip, pushkit

So, from iOS 10 SDK, there is not any background mode for VoIP applications that maintains connectivity for receiving calls when phone is locked, for example. The problem is that I sometimes have closed internet connection and Apple servers are unreachable, so using PushKit is not good in this scenario. Is there any way to be able to receive phone calls with background mode with iOS 10 SDK or is it like, go with PushKit and open connection for Apple servers? I know there are some, "hacks" like, play sound, but I know that Apple will reject app.

Comment: I haven't tested it but have you checked out CallKit? https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/230/

Comment: I've searched and on Apple developer forum, Apple staff answered: "There’s no supported way to do this.  To use CallKit you must link with the iOS 10 SDK, and if you link with the iOS 10 SDK you will not be able to use the legacy VoIP API." I see people filing bug reports for that

Comment: Our company and our customers are also suffering from VoIP background mode beeing removed from iOS 10. We operated in secure closed networks and it's a fundamental change for us.

We have posted technical request and the official response of Apple DTS team "There is no official way to support VoIP background operations without Push Kit."

They have also suggested firing a Bug Report which would go to the engineering team. We have done that and waiting for Apple's feedback.

Comment: The only thing you can do at the moment is to keep building your app against iOS 9 SDK. VoIP app would remain operational in the background on iOS 10 devices due to backward compatibility mode.

Comment: @ViktorKrykun Yes, that seems to be the way to go but I can't seem to set iOS9 as the base SDK in XCode 8. Did you have any luck there? Have a separate question here for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443647/xcode-8-swift-3-and-ios-9-3-base-sdk