# XCode 8, Swift 3 and iOS 9.3 Base SDK

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have looked around for all relevant XCode questions/answers but couldn't find a a solution.

What I need to do is to have my project in XCode 8 & Swift 3 and build it with the base SDK of iOS 9.x.

What I have done:

1. Downloaded XCode 7 and copied over the relevant iOS 9.x SDKs to XCode 8.
2. Created a new basic project in XCode 8 (Swift 3).
3. Changed the base SDK to iOS 9.3.
4. Hit the Run button.

The error that I get is: `<unknown>:0: error: Swift does not support the SDK 'iPhoneOS9.3.sdk'
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1`

Can we conclude that you can't have base SDK as iOS 9.3 in XCode 8?

Comment: Why do you want a Base SDK of 9.3 with Xcode 8? There's no reason for that. Use Xcode 8.1 with a Base SDK of "latest" (iOS 10.1 at the moment) and a Deployment Target of 9.3 (or whatever earliest version you wish to support).

Comment: Yep, I know that the deployment target will let me push the app to 9.3 users but that isn't the goal here. One of the libraries that I am using is crashing when the base SDK is iOS10+. The crash is due to the change in VoIP logic in iOS 10 (sockets). So, I really need to build with iOS 9.

Comment: Either use Xcode 7 (and Swift 2.3), fix the library, or find a library that supports your needs of Swift 3/iOS 10.

Comment: Library isn't mine, I don't think there is an alternative to the library as it is a VoIP library (also the heart of the app). The only option is XCode 7 and I really want to avoid that.

Comment: I agree with rmaddy, you shouldn't be using the iOS 9 sdk on Xcode 8.  The library you are using was probably made using an older version of swift and is not compatible with the version of swift that comes with Xcode 8.  For this reason, many Shared Library creators have opted to writing in objective-c since it is stable.  Swift on the other hand is not backwards compatible.  try reaching out to the creators of the library and ask for a version that works with swift 3.  I am assuming you are using swift 3.